# how to avoid nested switch?

Tags: javascript, nested, switch-statement

I'm creating a contextual menu in JavaScript for a web app. The menu can appear in numerous contexts, and have different choices. I could have a different function for each context/choice:

```
grid1_delete()
grid1_duplicate()
grid2_delete()
grid2_add()
grid2_duplicate()
```

and hard code those in as the menu is being built. The thing I don't like about that is there will probably be a lot of repeated code. So I was thinking about using a dispatcher function, but it's resulting in potentially long, nested switch statement thus:

```
function contextMenuClick(context, menuItem) {
    var action = menuItem.innerHTML;
    switch (context) {
        case 'grid1':
            switch(action) {
                 case('delete'):
                      // do delete for grid1
                      break;
                 case('duplicate'):
                      // do duplicate for grid1
                      break;
                 default:
                      console.log('undefined action in contextMenuClick/grid1: ' + context);
            }
            break;
        case 'grid2':
            switch(action) {
                 case('add'):
                      // do add for grid2
                      break;
                 case('delete'):
                      // do delete for grid2
                      break;
                 case('duplicate'):
                      // do duplicate for grid2
                      break;
                 default:
                      console.log('undefined action in contextMenuClick/grid2: ' + context);
            }
            break;
        default:
            console.log('undefined context in contextMenuClick: ' + context);
        }
```

Yuck. There's got to be a better way. Maybe the dispatcher is more trouble than it's worth. I've looked at some of [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496189/what-is-the-best-easiest-way-to-use-nested-switch-case-statements) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494506/dealing-with-nested-if-then-else-nested-switch-statements) [posts](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000486.html), but I'm not quite getting how to apply them to this exact situation.

Comment: Do different grids support different functions or do they all support the same set?

Comment: I'm not clear on how different grid1_delete and grid2_delete are.  Do they do the same things on different objects?  Or do they do fundamentally different things?   If the former, they should be combined into a single generic function.

Comment: The different grids support different functions. Even worse, different rows of the same grid support different functions, and/or similar functions that are acting on different types of objects. In theory some refactoring/paramaterization can occur, but maybe not in all cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Switch statements are very rarely necessary in Javascript.  In general, you can just use objects like dictionaries/maps and do the lookup directly: `foo.bar` is equivalent to `foo['bar']`.

Also, for "global" variables, `some_global_func()` is equivalent to `window.some_global_func()`, which can also be written as `var f = 'some_global_func'; window[f]()`: you don't *ever* need `eval` in order to select a variable or call a function dynamically based on its name.  In general, when doing that, though, you should prefer to store the function in an object rather than at global scope (i.e. in the `window` object).

So, assuming that `grid1_delete` and `grid2_delete` are fundamentally different and can't be combined into a generic function, you could do something like the following without changing your code much:

```
var grid_actions = {
    'grid1': {
        'delete': function() { /* ... */ },
        'duplicate': function() { /* ... */ }
    },
    'grid2': {
        'delete': function() { /* ... */ },
        'add': function() { /* ... */ },
        'duplicate': function() { /* ... */ }
    }
}

function contextMenuClick(context, menuItem) {
    var action = menuItem.innerHtml;
    if (context in grid_actions) {
        if (action in grid_actions[context]) {
            grid_actions[context][action]();
        } else {
            console.log('undefined action in contextMenuClick/' + context + ': ' + action);
        }
    } else {
        console.log('undefined context in contextMenuClick: ' + context);
    }
}
```

A better solution, though, is to refactor things to have have these functions be methods of objects for each context, like @[le dorfier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31641/le-dorfier) suggests.

Answer (score 2):

How about passing an actual object reference in for "context" instead of just a string? That way, you have just one switch statement:

```
function contextMenuClick(grid, menuItem) {
    var action = menuItem.innerHTML;
    switch(action) {
       case('delete'):
          grid.delete();
          break;
       case('duplicate'):
          grid.duplicate();
          break;
    }
}
```

Better yet, simply bind the handler directly to the correct object/method.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest good simplification is to have each switch all a function containing a switch.

If you have an object for each of your contexts, you can add a function to each object which accepts the menu as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of using eval(context + "_" + action + "();") would likely work, but is quite dangerous, as it would allow your client to execute a nearly arbitrary function in your script. (anything that matches X_Y).  Yes. eval is mostly evil.

How about

```
switch(context+"_"+action) { 
    case ("grid1_add"):  grid1_add(); 
[...]
}
```